# FTPHost.walk in ftputil connected to FTPS server not returning anything

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib, ftps

I'm trying to get a list of files and paths under a directory in an FTP site using ftputil's `walk` method:

```py
import ftputil
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

host = 'my_host'
user = 'my_user'
pw = 'my_pw'
folder = '/my/dir'

ftp = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, pw, session_factory=FTP_TLS)

for root,dirs,files in ftp.walk(folder):
    print(root, dirs, files)
```

However, nothing is printed. `ftp.walk(folder)` does return a generator object, but nothing is being generated. What am I missing? Maybe I'm not handling the TLS connection right (although I don't get any error)?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run `prot_p` as part of setting up the session:

```py
class TLSFTPSession(FTP_TLS):

    def __init__(self, host, userid, password):
        FTP_TLS.__init__(self)
        #self.set_debuglevel(2)
        self.connect(host, 21)
        self.login(userid, password)
        self.prot_p()

ftp = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, pw, session_factory=TLSFTPSession)
```

Then it works!